# ¿Como llamar a dos funciones para ingresar datos en un array?

Tags: javascript

como pone en el titulo tengo un programa que tiene dos array de objetos y un array para guardar los datos y a su vez debe tener dos funciones una para insertar libros y otra para insertar autores, cada libro puede tener varios autores y puedo insertar cuantos libros quiera el usuario; y mi problema surge en que no puedo hacer que después de recorrer la función registrar libros cuando llegue a la parte de cuantos autores quieres que tenga tu libro(ya que un libro puede tener varios autores)ejecute la función insertar autores y vuelva a la función insertar libros y compruebe los autores que tiene ese libro y compruebe que son esos los correctos y los imprima(que la funcion que imprime los datos no se si me funciona bien).
Aquí adjunto el código.

javascript código:

```
var biblioteca = new Array();


function libro(titulo, autores, anyo, editorial) {

    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.autores = autores;
    this.anyo = anyo;
    this.editorial = editorial;

}

function autor(nombre, apellidos, edad, nacionalidad) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.aepellidos = apellidos;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.nacionalidad = nacionalidad;

}

window.onload = function () {

    document.getElementById("mostrar").onclick = Mostrar;
    document.getElementById("insertar").onclick = insertarlibro;
    document.getElementById("insertar").onclick = insertarautor;
}

function insertarlibro() {

    var numlibros = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos libros vas a insertar"));
    for (let i = 0; i < numlibros; i++) {
        biblioteca.push(numlibros);
    }

    var titulo = prompt("Insertar el nombre del titulo del libro").toUpperCase();

    var anyo = parseInt(prompt("Año"));

    var editorial = prompt("Inserta su editorial");

    var numautores = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos autores vas a insertar"));
    for (let i = 0; i < numautores; i++) {
        autores.push(insertarautor);
    }

    var comprobar2 = false;
    var autores = prompt("¿Quien es el autor?");
    for (let i = 0; i < biblioteca.length; i++) {
        if (autores == biblioteca[i].nombre) {
            var newautor = new autor(nombre);
            biblioteca.push(newautor);
            comprobar2 = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (comprobar2 == false) {
        alert("Este autor " + nombre + " no existe");
    }

    var registrohecho = new libro(titulo, autores, anyo, editorial);

    return registrohecho;

}

console.log(insertarlibro);


function insertarautor() {

    var nombre = prompt("Insertar el nombre del autor").toUpperCase();

    var apellidos = prompt("Insertar el apellidos del autor").toUpperCase();

    var edad = parseInt(prompt("Edad"));

    var nacionalidad = prompt("¿De que pais es el autor?");

    var registrohecho = new autor(nombre, apellidos, edad, nacionalidad);

    return registrohecho;

}

console.log(insertarautor);

function Mostrar() {

    biblioteca.forEach(element => {
        var muestra = "Nombre del libro:" + element.libro + "autores: " + element.autor + " Año en el que se publico: " + element.anyo + "Editorial:" + element.editorial;
        document.write(muestra);
    });
}
```

aqui html:

```
<div id="insertar">
    <input type="button" value="Insertar">
</div>
<div id="mostrar">
    <input type="button" value="Mostrar">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

aca te dejo una pequeña implementación con clases y metodos, revisala y comentame. saludos.

```js
class Libro {
    constructor() {
      this.titulo = prompt("Insertar el nombre del titulo del libro").toUpperCase();
      this.year = parseInt(prompt("Año")) || 0;
      this.editorial = prompt("Inserta su editorial");
      this.autores = this.insertarAutores(parseInt(prompt("Cuantos autores vas a insertar")));
    }
    
    insertarAutores = ( cantidad ) => [...Array(cantidad)].map(i => new Autor())
}

class Autor{
    constructor(){
        this.nombre = prompt("Insertar el nombre del autor").toUpperCase();;
        this.aepellidos = prompt("Insertar el apellidos del autor").toUpperCase();;
        this.edad = parseInt(prompt("Edad")) || 0;
        this.nacionalidad = prompt("¿De que pais es el autor?");;
    }
}
  
class Libreria {
  
    constructor(divDestino) {
      this.libros = [];
      this.destino = divDestino
      this.divDestino = ""
    }
  
    agregarLibro = () => {
      this.divDestino = document.getElementById(this.destino);
      this.libros.push( new Libro() ) 
    }
    
    mostrar = () =>  this.divDestino.innerHTML = this.libros.map(libro => 
          `<div>
                Nombre del libro: ${libro.titulo} <br/>
                Año en el que se publico: ${libro.year}  <br/>
                Editorial: ${libro.editorial} <br/>
                Autores: 
                    <ol>
                        ${
                            libro.autores.map(autor => 
                                `<li>${JSON.stringify(autor).split(",").map(i=>i).join("<br/>")}`
                            ).join("</li>")
                                .replace(/[{}"]/g,"")
                                .replace(/[:]/g," : ")
                        }
                    </ol>
           </div>
    `).join("<br/>")
}


let libreria = new Libreria("salida");
```

```html
<div id="insertar">
  <input 
    type="button" 
    value="Insertar" 
    onclick="libreria.agregarLibro()"
   >
</div>
<div id="mostrar">
  <input 
    type="button" 
    value="Mostrar"
    onclick="libreria.mostrar()"
    >
</div>

<div id="salida"></div>
```

Comment: No puedo usar jquery, aun asi te agradezco la respuesta

Comment: no hay jquery, es JavaScript vanilla toda la respuesta.

Comment: ${libro.titulo} eso es sugar sintax, o literal, es lo mismo que poner "soy un texto" + soyUnaVariable + " y aca sigue el texto" , pero pones `soy un texto ${soyUnaVariable} y aca sigue el texto` , se usa esta comilla ` mirate esto --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678052/usage-of-the-backtick-character-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo conseguí resolver, fue añadir un array dentro de la funcion que

`insertarlibros` que fuera recogiendo el numero de autores que quería que tuviese cada libro.
Aquí dejo el código arreglado.

```
var biblioteca = new Array();


function libro(titulo, autores, anyo, editorial) {

    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.autores = autores;
    this.anyo = anyo;
    this.editorial = editorial;

}

function autor(nombre, apellidos, edad, nacionalidad) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.aepellidos = apellidos;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.nacionalidad = nacionalidad;

}

window.onload = function () {

    document.getElementById("mostrar").onclick = Mostrar;
    document.getElementById("insertar").onclick = insertarlibro;
    document.getElementById("insertar").onclick = insertarautor;
}

function insertarlibro() {
    var autores = new Array();
    var titulo = prompt("Insertar el nombre del titulo del libro");
    var anyo = parseInt(prompt("Año"));
    var editorial = prompt("Inserta su editorial");
    var numautores = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos autores vas a insertar"));
    for (let i = 0; i < numautores; i++) {
        let autor = insertarautor();
        autores.push(autor);
    }


    var registrohecho = new libro(titulo, autores, anyo, editorial);

    return registrohecho;


}

console.log(insertarlibro);


function insertarautor() {

    var nombre = prompt("Insertar el nombre del autor").toUpperCase();
    var apellidos = prompt("Insertar el apellidos del autor").toUpperCase();

    var edad = parseInt(prompt("Edad"));
    var nacionalidad = prompt("¿De que pais es el autor?");   
    var registrohecho = new autor(nombre, apellidos, edad, nacionalidad);

    return registrohecho;


}

console.log(insertarautor);

var numlibros = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos libros vas a insertar"));
for (let i = 0; i < numlibros; i++) {
    var insertalibro = insertarlibro();
    biblioteca.push(insertalibro);

}
```