# Imprimir un objeto y que no aparezca el texto [[object Object]]

Tags: javascript

Tengo este programa que nada más iniciarlo te pide que ingreses el número de libros que quieres registrar y, a su vez, te pide el número de autores que tiene ese libro e ingresar sus datos (nombre, apellidos etc).

El problema surge que a la hora de imprimir los datos. Aparece en la parte en la que se deberían imprimir los datos de autores con el texto `[object Object]`.

A traves de un `console.log` sí soy capaz de sacar los datos, pero yo quiero sacarlos también a través de un `documnet.write`.

También he intentado poner `elements.autores.nombre` para solo sacar el nombre del autor del libro, pero me aparece `undefined`.

Dicho esto, dejo el código entero para que lo prueben:

```js
var biblioteca = new Array();


function libro(titulo, autores, anyo, editorial) {

    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.autores = autores;
    this.anyo = anyo;
    this.editorial = editorial;

}

function autor(nombre, apellidos, edad, nacionalidad) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.aepellidos = apellidos;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.nacionalidad = nacionalidad;

}

window.onload = function () {

    document.getElementById("mostrar").onclick = Mostrar;
    document.getElementById("insertar").onclick = insertarlibro;
    document.getElementById("insertar").onclick = insertarautor;
}

function insertarlibro() {
    var autores = new Array();
    var titulo = prompt("Insertar el nombre del titulo del libro");
    var anyo = parseInt(prompt("Año"));
    var editorial = prompt("Inserta su editorial");
    var numautores = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos autores vas a insertar"));
    for (let i = 0; i < numautores; i++) {
        let autor = insertarautor();
        autores.push(autor);
    }

    var registrohecho = new libro(titulo, autores, anyo, editorial);

    return registrohecho;


}

console.log(insertarlibro);


function insertarautor() {

    var nombre = prompt("Insertar el nombre del autor").toUpperCase();
    var apellidos = prompt("Insertar el apellidos del autor").toUpperCase();
    var edad = parseInt(prompt("Edad"));
    var nacionalidad = prompt("¿De que pais es el autor?");
    var registrohecho = new autor(nombre, apellidos, edad, nacionalidad);

    return registrohecho;

}

console.log(insertarautor);

var numlibros = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos libros vas a insertar"));
for (let i = 0; i < numlibros; i++) {
    var insertalibro = insertarlibro();
    biblioteca.push(insertalibro);

}


function Mostrar() {

    biblioteca.forEach(element => {
        console.log("Error" + JSON.stringify(element.autores));
        var muestra = "Nombre del libro:" + element.titulo + " autores: " + element.autores + " Año en el que se publico: " + element.anyo + " Editorial: " + element.editorial;
        document.write(muestra);
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="insertar">
    <input type="button" value="Insertar">
</div>
<div id="mostrar">
    <input type="button" value="Mostrar">
</div>
```

Comment: Estás imprimiendo `element.autores` lo que es un array.

Comment: He redactado una respuesta explicándote el motivo por el que sale ese texto y, además, cómo hacer que salga otro diferente.

Comment: Esta pregunta esta respondida en la otra pregunta que hiciste, si te fijas en la parte que pensaste que era jquery. --> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/499659/como-hacer-un-array-anidado-en-objetos-y-recorrelo/499673?noredirect=1#comment888739_499673

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como hacer un array anidado en objetos y recorrelo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/499659/como-hacer-un-array-anidado-en-objetos-y-recorrelo)

Comment: @FacundoE.Villagra , aunque el autor y parte del código sean iguales, la duda que se plantea en cada una de las preguntas es completamente diferente. Además, él mismo resolvió su duda y la compartió como respuesta. Quizá deberías preguntarle (en la otra pregunta) si tu respuesta fue de ayuda para resolver su problema la marque como respuesta correcta.

Comment: Asi es era otra pregunta distinta, he cambiado el titulo para evitar confusiones, lo siento por las molestias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cuando se quiere concatenar una cadena de caracteres a una clase, se realiza una llamada al método [`Object.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) de dicha clase para convertir el contenido en una cadena que pueda ser concatenada.

Por defecto dicho método mostrará el texto `[object Object]`, pero puedes crear tu propio método `toString()` personalizado para hacer el trabajo con mayor flexibilidad:

```
/* Mi método personalizado */
function miToStringGenerico() {
    return JSON.stringify(this);
}
```

Por lo que al asignarlo a cualquier variable, al mostrar su contenido se aplicará `JSON.stringify()` al contenido:

```js
/* Mi método personalizado */
function miToStringGenerico() {
    return JSON.stringify(this);
}

/* Datos básicos de ejemplo */
let pruebas = { a: 1, b: 2 };

/* Ahora se llamará al toString por defecto para concatenar el contenido */
console.log("Resultado: " + pruebas);
/* Resultado: [object Object] */

/* Ahora se concatenará usando la función toString propia */
pruebas.toString = miToStringGenerico;
console.log("Resultado: " + pruebas);
/* Resultado: {"a":1,"b":2} */
```

Se puede generar un `toString()` personalizado para los datos en el formato que se desee. Puedes ver un ejemplo más abajo.

---

Aquí tienes un ejemplo con datos genéricos:

```js
var biblioteca = new Array();

/* Mi método personalizado */
function miToStringGenerico() {
    return JSON.stringify(this);
}

function libro(titulo, autores, anyo, editorial) {

    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.autores = autores;
    this.anyo = anyo;
    this.editorial = editorial;

}

function autor(nombre, apellidos, edad, nacionalidad) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.aepellidos = apellidos;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.nacionalidad = nacionalidad;

}

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("mostrar").onclick = Mostrar;
    document.getElementById("insertar").onclick = insertarlibro;
    document.getElementById("insertar").onclick = insertarautor;
}

function insertarlibro() {
    var autores = new Array();
    var titulo = prompt("Insertar el nombre del titulo del libro");
    var anyo = parseInt(prompt("Año"));
    var editorial = prompt("Inserta su editorial");
    var numautores = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos autores vas a insertar"));
    for (let i = 0; i < numautores; i++) {
        let autor = insertarautor();
        /* Aquí genero el método "toString" para que use el nuestro */
        autor.toString = miToStringGenerico;
        autores.push(autor);
    }

    var registrohecho = new libro(titulo, autores, anyo, editorial);

    return registrohecho;


}

function insertarautor() {

    var nombre = prompt("Insertar el nombre del autor").toUpperCase();
    var apellidos = prompt("Insertar el apellidos del autor").toUpperCase();
    var edad = parseInt(prompt("Edad"));
    var nacionalidad = prompt("¿De que pais es el autor?");
    var registrohecho = new autor(nombre, apellidos, edad, nacionalidad);

    return registrohecho;

}

var numlibros = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos libros vas a insertar"));
for (let i = 0; i < numlibros; i++) {
    var insertalibro = insertarlibro();
    biblioteca.push(insertalibro);
}


function Mostrar() {
    biblioteca.forEach(element => {
        console.log("Error" + JSON.stringify(element.autores));
        var muestra = "Nombre del libro:" + element.titulo + " autores: " + element.autores + " Año en el que se publico: " + element.anyo + " Editorial: " + element.editorial;
        document.write(muestra);
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="insertar">
    <input type="button" value="Insertar">
</div>
<div id="mostrar">
    <input type="button" value="Mostrar">
</div>
```

---

Y aquí un ejemplo con los datos específicos del autor:

```
/* Mi método particular */
function autorToString() {
    return `
      <p>Apellidos, nombre: ${this.apellidos}, ${this.nombre}</p>
      <p>Edad: ${this.edad}</p>
      <p>Nacionalidad: ${this.nacionalidad}</p>
    `;
}
```

Puedes ver el resultado aquí:

```js
var biblioteca = new Array();

/* Mi método particular */
function autorToString() {
    return `
      <p>Apellidos, nombre: ${this.apellidos}, ${this.nombre}</p>
      <p>Edad: ${this.edad}</p>
      <p>Nacionalidad: ${this.nacionalidad}</p>
    `;
}

function libro(titulo, autores, anyo, editorial) {

    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.autores = autores;
    this.anyo = anyo;
    this.editorial = editorial;

}

function autor(nombre, apellidos, edad, nacionalidad) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.nacionalidad = nacionalidad;

}

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("mostrar").onclick = Mostrar;
    document.getElementById("insertar").onclick = insertarlibro;
    document.getElementById("insertar").onclick = insertarautor;
}

function insertarlibro() {
    var autores = new Array();
    var titulo = prompt("Insertar el nombre del titulo del libro");
    var anyo = parseInt(prompt("Año"));
    var editorial = prompt("Inserta su editorial");
    var numautores = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos autores vas a insertar"));
    for (let i = 0; i < numautores; i++) {
        let autor = insertarautor();
        /* Aquí genero el método "toString" para que use el nuestro */
        autor.toString = autorToString;
        autores.push(autor);
    }

    var registrohecho = new libro(titulo, autores, anyo, editorial);

    return registrohecho;


}

function insertarautor() {

    var nombre = prompt("Insertar el nombre del autor").toUpperCase();
    var apellidos = prompt("Insertar el apellidos del autor").toUpperCase();
    var edad = parseInt(prompt("Edad"));
    var nacionalidad = prompt("¿De que pais es el autor?");
    var registrohecho = new autor(nombre, apellidos, edad, nacionalidad);

    return registrohecho;

}

var numlibros = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos libros vas a insertar"));
for (let i = 0; i < numlibros; i++) {
    var insertalibro = insertarlibro();
    biblioteca.push(insertalibro);
}


function Mostrar() {
    biblioteca.forEach(element => {
        console.log("Error" + JSON.stringify(element.autores));
        var muestra = "Nombre del libro:" + element.titulo + " autores: " + element.autores + " Año en el que se publico: " + element.anyo + " Editorial: " + element.editorial;
        document.write(muestra);
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="insertar">
    <input type="button" value="Insertar">
</div>
<div id="mostrar">
    <input type="button" value="Mostrar">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> De la forma que codificaste cada libro es un
> objeto{titulo:'',año:..editorial:''..autores:[{autor}..{..}} autores
> es un array de objetos autor. Para acceder a ellos tenes que tener en
> cuenta lo anterior en Mostar()   A modo de ejemplo y con el solo fin
> de mostrar el accedo a los mismos si ingresa 1 libro con dos
> autores así si funciona..Luego podes generalizar si tenes en cuenta lo >anterior en la funcion Mostrar() utilizando length

```js
function Mostrar() {

    biblioteca.forEach(element => {
        // sin acceso con //console.log(element.autores);
console.log('element',element.autores[0],element.autores[1])
      console.log("Muestra" + element.autores[0].nombre,element.autores[1].nombre)
        var muestra = "Nombre del libro:" + element.titulo + " autores: " + element.autores[0].nombre+'..'+element.autores[1].nombre + " Año en el que se publico: " + element.anyo + " Editorial: " + element.editorial;
        console.log(muestra);
       document.write(muestra);
    });
}
```

Comment: Intentare sacarlo tambien mediante un bucle, asi mejoro mi habilidad con estos, gracias por el consejo.

Comment: Si no tenias en cuenta la estructura de los objetos que creaste así como te  muestro si funciona sin errores el error era no tener en cuenta por ejemplo que autores es un array de objetos .Determina la longitud del array de autores luego con for (leti = 0; i < (longitud autores); i++) { ...accedes a cada uno de ellos }